# My react native project's release signed apk is not opening in the device and also it is creating in very small size

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle, apk, release

I am having a problem with react-native for 2 days, I can build my project successfully for debug and the debug file is working perfectly fine, but when I create release APK and AAB file then both of the APK and AAB is generating in very small size and I think it is the reason it doesn't launch on devices. I try a lot of solutions on the Internet and Stack Overflow, but nothing worked.

This is my project root build.gradle

```
  buildscript {
      ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 22
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "17.0.0"
      }
  repositories {
       google() 
       jcenter()
       mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
       classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
  }
}

 allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google() 
          maven {
              url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
          }
         maven {
              url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
          }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
     }
   }
```

This is app/build.gradle

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.6, 
        0.99.99]'
    }
 }

  apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

  apply plugin: "com.android.application"

  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

  apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"


  import com.android.build.OutputFile

  /**
   * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. 
   bundleDebugJsAndAssets
   * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
   * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the 
     Android build
   * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we 
     prefer to load the
   * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible 
     configurations
   * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add 
     it before the
   * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
   *
   * project.ext.react = [
   *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
   *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
   *
   *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
   *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
   *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
   *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
   *
   *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
   *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
   *
   *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
   *   bundleInDebug: false,
   *
   *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
   *   bundleInRelease: true,
   *
   *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
   *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC- 
          Build-Variants
   *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
   *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
   *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
   *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
   *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
   *   // bundleInBeta: true,
   *
   *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only 
          disabled in release)
   *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
   *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
   *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
   *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
   *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
   *
   *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
   *   root: "../../",
   *
   *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
   *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
   *
   *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
   *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
   *
   *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you 
          use via
   *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
   *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
   *
   *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you 
          use via
   *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
   *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
   *
   *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets 
          change; this means
   *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the 
          tasks are up to
   *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance 
          reasons (gradle
   *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS 
          files in android/
   *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
   *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
   *
   *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
   *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
   *
   *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
   *   extraPackagerArgs: []
   * ]
   */

   project.ext.react = [
      devDisabledInDev: true,
      bundleInDebug: true,
      enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
   ]

   apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

   /**
   * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
   *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
   *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
   * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
   * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
   * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
   */
  def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

   /**
  * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
  */
  def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

  /**
  * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
  *
  * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
  * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
  *
  * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
  * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
  * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
  * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
  */
  def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

  /**
  * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
  *
  * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
  * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
  * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
  */
  def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

  android {
     ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
     compileSdkVersion 30
  compileOptions {
     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
  defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.lcdbaba"
     minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
     targetSdk 31
     versionCode 5
     versionName '1.0.2'
     multiDexEnabled true
  }
  splits {
      abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
      }
   }
  signingConfigs {
   debug {
       storeFile file('debug.keystore')
       storePassword '123456'
       keyAlias 'alias'
       keyPassword '123456'
   }
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
     buildTypes {
  //        debug {
  //            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
  //        }
    release {
        // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
        // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard- 
        rules.pro"
    }
}

   // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
      applicationVariants.all { variant ->
      variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as 
           described here:
        // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
        // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, 
           etc.
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release 
        variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
        }

    }
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.5.1'
implementation project(':lottie-react-native')

implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1' 
//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
compile project(':react-native-otp-verify')
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'

implementation project(':react-native-razorpay')

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.1')

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
  exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
}

if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}

compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')


    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2"
}

     // Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
     // puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
       task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
           from configurations.compile
           into 'libs'
       }



   apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform- 
   android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution of this problem:

Step 1:-

```
    if you are facing the same problem then first create the debug 
    release build from the android studio, and then analyze the apk and 
    check do you have the lib folder in your apk if you don't have the 
    lib folder then follow 2 step.
```

Step 2:-

```
    Add the following to gradle.properties
    android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs = false
```

Step 3:-

```
    Add the following in your  android/app/build.gradel
    sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
```

step 4:-

```
    Now restart your android studio and sync your gradel and then create 
    release apk.
```